# How quickly do relays wear out?

Tags: relay

I have a generic 5 V [DPDT relay](https://www.nteinc.com/relay_web/pdf/R40.pdf). I plan to use it in a situation where it's switched on and off quite frequently. Let's say it goes on and off every 10 seconds for a total of 6 times per minute. Obviously it'll stop working at some point, but when exactly is that time?

Comment: Do you have a datasheet for the relay? I recognize that it's a generic relay, but sometimes resellers will still provide a simple datasheet of the product they're reselling, even if it looks generic. Also, what is the load you are putting through the relay and what is the rated voltage/current of the relay? High voltages and currents cause damage when the relay is switching that wears it out faster.

Comment: i think the datasheet should be this one: https://www.nteinc.com/relay_web/pdf/R40.pdf
the load is relatively small compared to the rated voltage/current, so i don't think it makes much of a difference

Comment: If you severely overload it, 1/2 cycle.  Could you please _edit your question_ with more details about the voltage and current that you'll be switching, and whether the load is capacitive or inductive.  While you're editing, it would be nice if you could include the link to your datasheet _in your question_ (it's a Stackexchange thing).  Don't be surprised if someone suggests solid-state alternatives -- there's a reason that the world is moving away from electromechanical relays unless they're really needed.

Answer (score 5):

Based on datasheet referenced in comments:

- Mechanical Life: 10,000,000 operations min
- Electrical Life: 300,000 @ 2A, 30 VDC
- 500,000 @ 0.5A, 120 VAC

and "load is relatively small compared to the rated voltage/current", let's assume 0.5A, 120V AC. (As I understand it, in general higher current or higher voltage can wear out a relay faster, and DC faster than AC.)

500,000 / (6 (per minute) * 60 (minutes per hour) * 24 (hours per day)) = 500,000 / 8,640 = 57 days.

That's assuming continuous operation and that it magically fails at exactly the 500,000 point. Depending on a lot of factors, you may get much longer life or much shorter life.

Comment: Note that if you can disconnect the load by other means before actuating the relay (thereby actuating under zero load conditions) you can drastically increase the life of a relay. This is how industrial and test equipment that switches relays on and off all the time manages to survive so long.

Comment: 10 million cycles the same rate is 3 years 61 days.

Comment: @DDuck Agreed. But my take on "mechanical life" is that if the relay was run with no electrical load at all then that is the expected life. Which is only valid if the relay is being used for the beautiful clicking sound :-)

Comment: Or as @hearth says turn the off current to the contacts then switch